# Is it possible to change theme/style for Epiphany so that the active tab is standing out more?

Tags: release-hera, epiphany

Does anyone know if possible and if so how to change the theming/styling of Epiphany so that the active tab is standing out more. I find it hard to easily see which tab is active.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Please expose all usability issues you find to the [elementary theme’s bug tracker](https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/issues).